# How to filter Java Streams using Files.getAttribute

Tags: java, java-stream, java-nio

I am trying to filter files that were created more recent than another file. I just don't get how to apply the methods from `Files` directly to the stream.

Is there a neater way to do it?, I know it does not help readability to use Streams for the application but Im trying to learn to use it.

```
try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(dir,1)) {
                res = stream.filter(Files::isDirectory).filter(
                     f->Files.getAttribute(f,"creationTime")>
                     Files.getAttribute(reference, "creationTime"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Just an observation to say that not all file systems support a file creation timestamp

Answer (score 4):

You cannot compare a "creationTime" / `FileTime`  with ">". If you view source of `Files.isDirectory(path)` and `Files.getAttribute(path,attr)` you will see that both read the underlying filesystem attributes - so two filters are re-reading similar definitions.

Switching to `Files.find` provides a much neater way to scan as it retrieves file attributes automatically and passes both the filesystem path and attribute to a bi-predicate. This makes it easier to pre-filter a `Files.find` stream firstly on directory and then by comparing the creation times using built-in `time1.isAfter(time2)`. Something like this:

```
Instant refTime = Files.readAttributes(reference, BasicFileAttributes.class).creationTime().toInstant();
try(var dirs = Files.find(dir, 1 /*depth*/, (p,a) -> 
         a.isDirectory() && a.creationTime().toInstant().isAfter(refTime))) {
    List<Path> recentDirs = dirs.collect(Collectors.toList());
    ...
}
```